# Network Reachability with UIWebView

Tags: iphone, xcode, networking, app-store

i just finished my first app which is a fullscreen view of my web app. it works fine and i was about to submit it but i noticed that apple requires network Reachability. I have tried many ways of doing this, both seating for the network and finding the UIWebViews errors but none have worked. If anyone can give me the link to a working tutorial or explain this to me, it would be much appreciated... thanks! BTW- I am using a single view application

Comment: I'm pretty sure they don't require it, as I've submitted a few apps without it.

Comment: right, but this is a full webview. It's the entire app. If there's no internet its a blank screen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I uploaded an app to the store without Reachability, but later I read on the Apple Documentation that a message to the user is required when there's no connection to the internet (however my app was approved). I think Apple is not much strict about this, but it is a good programming practice to provide some feedback to the user when something goes bad.

So, I strongly recommend you to use Reachability in your project.

Here's the Apple sample code: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html

If you use the code above you could implement somethig like this:

```
//Check connection
Reachability *r = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"m.google.com"];
NetworkStatus internetStatus = [r currentReachabilityStatus];
if(internetStatus == NotReachable){

    NSLog(@"There's no connection");

    UIAlertView *errorAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                 initWithTitle:@"No internet connection"
                 message:@"Internet connection is required to use this app"
                 delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [errorAlertView show];

}else
    NSLog(@"Internet connection is OK");
```

Remember to import the Rechability files

```
#import "Reachability.h"
```

If you're developing with the new ARC feature, here's a modified version of Reachability: https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability (The page provides good sample code)

I've use both versions and they work pretty well.

Happy coding.

Comment: Thanks, But how would i implement that? Thats what i ALWAYS get stuck on. Im kinda a newbie to this and this is my first app that i am submitting, but whenever i try to implement the way videos show it nothing happens. Ive added the framework and imported the file, but still nothing! When you don't have internet connection with my app the screen stays white and nothing happens.

Comment: Are you using ARC? Let me know so I can help you with some code.

Comment: 1. Import reachability.h and .m 2. Import systemconfig framework 3.import reachability.h into my viewcontroller.h 3.put that code in to ??? (What file do i put the sample code in, and that will it do? Does it only put it in the output? Whatabout an alert?

Comment: 1. You only need to import the .h file. 3. You can use the code I paste abode in the viewDidLoad method, only paste the code. Let me edit the answers with an UIAlertView.

Comment: Wow thank you so much, i couldn't have done this with out you... thanks ;) and ill send you the name of the app when its on the app store!

Comment: You're welcome, please mark the questiom as answered by clicking on the checkmsrk. I'll wait for the app's name :D

Answer (score 0):

Apple has some Reachability [sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html).

In my experience, Reachability is good practice but I wasn't aware that it is required.

Answer (score 0):

Apple does not require Reachability, per se.  They do, however, require that your app stays responsive and does something reasonable, even if the network is unavailable, not working properly, or goes down.

So test your app in Airplane mode, and maybe also in WIFI mode with the cable to the back of your WIFI access point unplugged.  If the UI of your app locks up or looks dead, fix it.